# Nested loop for foreign key in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, nested-loops, one-to-many

Newby to Django here. I need to list some music genres and their subgenres. I got the genres just fine, but I'm not sure how to list the subgenres.

This is my model:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    genre_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=4)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'genre'
        db_table_comment = 'Music genre catalog'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Subgenre(models.Model):
    subgenre_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=6)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'subgenre'
        db_table_comment = 'Music subgenre catalog'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

This is what I have in views.py:

```
def new_playlist(request):
    genres = Genre.objects.all().order_by('description')
    subgenres = Subgenre.objects.all()
    context = { 'genres':genres, 'subgenres':subgenres }
    return render(request,"applications/ecommerce/playlists/new-playlist.html",context)
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
{% for genre in genres %}

<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
      <h5 class="mb-0">{{genre.description}}</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">

      {% for subgenre in subgenres.genre.all %}

      <div class="row">
         <label>{{subgenre.description}}</label>
      </div>

      {% endfor %}

   </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in the opposite direction:

```
{% for genre in genres %}
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
      <h5 class="mb-0">{{ genre.description }}</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
      {% for subgenre in genre.subgenre_set.all %}
      <div class="row">
         <label>{{ subgenre.description }}</label>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and as view:

```
def new_playlist(request):
    genres = Genre.objects.prefetch_related('subgenre_set').order_by(
        'description'
    )
    context = {'genres': genres}
    return render(
        request, 'applications/ecommerce/playlists/new-playlist.html', context
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried what you suggested and I get this error: column subgenre.genre_id does not exist. HINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "subgenre.subgenre_id" or the column "subgenre.genre".

Comment: It seems that the table for your `Subgenre` model has no `subgenre_id` column (and perhaps not a `genre_id` either).

Comment: Hmm. That's weird. They show in my migration file and also when running python manage.py inspectdb. Also, this is from pgAdmin 4: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_8WhueuI8Yb9nTbUkM2ubhND2fqAmRtS/view

Comment: @AntonioRomo: you set `managed = False`, so that means Django does not migrate the model, it simply assumes you need to update the table accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again. I changed those to True, created a new migration and migrated. But I still get the same error. Sorry for the many questions. :/

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as the correct one. I understand my issue is different now. Thank you so much for all your help!!